# Latitude and Longitude MySQL Field Type

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I have a large set of Latitude and Longitude that I need to store in a MySQL database.  I am reading conflicting advice on the field type to use.

An example of the data is...

```
Lat        |  Long
------------------------
53.670827  |  -1.093991
50.894701  |  0.061115
52.288213  |  -1.822060
```

According to [this document](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1) from Google, they recommend the field type to be FLOAT(10,6)

I have tried this and when entering **57.098554** it gets changed to **57.098553**, however entering **-2.252504** stores correctly.

As an alternative, I was planning on using the following...

```
Lat DECIMAL(10, 8)
Long DECIMAL(11,8)
```

Does anybody have a better suggestion or am I right with the DECIMAL settings?

Comment: Use int? Multiplying every value with 10^6 on insert?

Comment: Float stores data in approximate value and it has upper and lower bound, and moreover for storing the `lat` and `lng` you should be using spiral extension http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: I also had the same issue some time ago and I solved it by using the decimals in the same way as you did - here's a detailed example on to accomplish this if you by any chance use Doctrine: http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2015/04/10/how-to-store-latitude-and-longitude-in-mysql/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are wrong! The google document you have linked to is from 2009, mysql has come a long way since then. Particularly the introduction of JSON and wait for it .... [spatial data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-datatypes.html) types in mysql 5.7

Since it's introduction, the correct way to store a location is as a POINT field. This also open up a range of spatial data functions for you. Things that you would otherwise need to write by hand as indeed developers had to do before it's introduction.

The built in geospatial functions are capable of using indexes while home made functions are often slower due to being unable to make proper use of indexes.

Comment: Thank you!  I hadn't noticed the date that Google article was from and how old it was.  Just looking at POINT now

Comment: If I also wanted to store the original separate long and lat fields would my DECIMAL field types from above be appropriate?

Comment: no it would be redundant. Lat and Lng can be retrieved from the POINT type quite easily

Comment: It is not redundant if I have a requirement to store them as two separate fields

Comment: it still is redundant. Because you are saving the same data twice. Saving lat and lng as two separate fields is an obsolete way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `FLOAT( 10, 6 )`.

see google map solutions: [Creating a Store Locator on Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator)